# How do I map Parallels shared home directory as a normal user instead of root?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, parallels

I am using Parallels in order to be able to use the same code across multiple platforms without needing any kind of sync mechanism.

This worked really well but there is one serious downside, the mounted folder is owned by `root` and this is forcing me to use root account on the VM.

This is clearly not a good security practice and also prevents me from discovering bugs that would be visible only when running as a normal user.

How can I address this problem? I was not able to find any options in Parallels for choosing the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using this approach:

Cat `/etc/mtab` and copy the line from there to `/etc/fstab` and adding `uid=xxx,gid=xxx`.

Also change the `/media/psf/Home` with `/home/xxx`

Doing a `mount -a` and after this you do share share same home account for your user.

Be sure that you can login as root on the VM because if you make a mistake you don't want to end-up lockedout of your machine.

Comment: I think you use `none` as the first field in `fstab`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried something like `none /home/sorins prl_fs sync,nosuid,nodev,noatime,share 0 0` but I always get an error when I try `mount -a`. I found very few examples of using prl_fs online and all of them seem to be old, since Parallels was not allowing for more than one shared folder.

Comment: I wasn't sure, hence only used a comment. Anything in `dmesg`?

Comment: That was the first thing to check, nothing is logged to dmesg. Check http://updates.virtuozzo.com/doc/pcs/en_us/virtuozzo/6/current/html/Virtuozzo_Users_Guide/35698.htm